# How to, on click, set select option to the same data-target as button clicked data-target?

Tags: javascript, html

How do you select the `data-target` of a `select` option using JavaScript? For example, if the user clicks the button below, how do you take that `data-target` value and have the select option with the matching `data-target` value become the selected option?

```
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".dropdown")...? = document.querySelector(".btn").dataset.target;
}

<button class="btn" data-target="2345">2345</button>

<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="one" data-target="1234">One</option>
    <option value="two" data-target="2345">Two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the option with an attribute selector and set its selected property to `true`.

```
document.querySelector(".dropdown option[data-target='"
 + document.querySelector(".btn").dataset.target + "']").selected = true;
```